# "promisify" a modal and wait for the resolve/reject (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I have a question about this package: [react-modal-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-promise). It is like a wrapper around a modal, and then you can use the modal as a promise.

An example:

```
MyModal().then(() => console.log('resolved!')).catch(() => console.log('rejected!'));
```

The modal component would look like this (simplified!):

```
const MyModal = () => {
  return (
    <Modal>
      <Pressable onPress={resolve}>
        <Text>Resolve this modal</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable onPress={reject}>
        <Text>Reject this modal</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

How can I achieve this in react native? I want to upload a photo to my server. When the user clicks a button, I want to open a modal where the user can select a photo and resolve it, after the modal resolve, the photo should be uploaded.

I know I can include my normal modal inside the JSX code, but I am curious about how this package works.

It's for react native.

Comment: I see no reason why that package would not work in react native. However, your syntax is wrong, according to [the docs](https://github.com/cudr/react-modal-promise#how-to-use) it needs to be `const MyModal = createModal(({onResolve, onReject}) => (<Modal>…</Modal));` if you want to call `MyModal().then(…)`.